# System.Data.SqlClient imported nuget package into library

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, nuget

I imported into my application's library `System.Data.SqlClient` which I can also see in my `.csproj` file, but as soon as I run my app, I get an exception thrown.

The two images show the details...

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

p.s. After downgrading `System.Data.SqlClient` to `4.6.1`, I get a similar error, below. This keeps happening; after installing that, I get an error about `4.4.0` and so on...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you have added nuget package in your library project(.dll). You need to add nuget reference in your main project where this library got referenced.

Comment: How do I first remove the one I have already downloaded and imported in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a lower version of `System.Data.SqlClient` because your project is .net core 2.

Please use the following package.

```
Uninstall-Package System.Data.SqlClient
Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.6.1
```

Comment: Do you mean `import` the lower version via Nuget again, or just modify that line in library `.csproj` file?

Comment: you can uninstall before nuget and then install new nuget

Comment: I did exactly that, but now I get the same error with a different version `4.5.0`. Can you please see my edited question? I have included a screenshot showing the new message...